# How to stream image file into a SQL DataSource with AjaxFileUpload?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to upload multiple files into a SQL database using `AjaxFileUpload`. I have a method that I use to upload a single file; in the aspx page with:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="file_Image" runat="server"/>
```

And in the aspx.cs page with:

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload FileUpload1 = file_Image;

    // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
    string filePath = file_Image.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        Stream fs = file_Image.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);}}
```

However, how can I use something similar for `AjaxFileUpload` or is it even possible to stream image data like this from the Ajax control? Thanks a million for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Thanks for your response; I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 (SQL Server Management Studio)

Comment: I guess this is a complicated question; However, is there any method that I could approach?

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with?  A control that allows for multiple file uploads or saving to the database?

Comment: Saving to the database, I'm able to upload 4 columns to the db using the AjaxFileUpload, but when it comes to the image data I'm not sure what method to use to insert the varbinary or image DataType. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Refer New `AjaxFileUpload` control in `AjaxToolKit`][1] http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

This new AjaxFileUpload control supports multiple file upload at once. but it comes with some limitation that IE10 or Chrome latest version support this.

This is very reliable, I am using this.

**Simple way to convert AjaxFileUpload file content into sql varbinary array:**

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
byte[] image = e.GetContents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Romil! I checked that sample before, but it only saves to the file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot Romil! Second method to GetContents() worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.